# Change user information in Firebase on password change (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I've recently implemented a change password functionality in my app with Firebase - the user will click on an item and get sent an email. This is hooked up through the login function, which checks firebase to look for an 'active' boolean. If it is false, the user will be re-directed to the change password page.

What my issue is now is that once the password is changed, I want to connect to Firebase and flip 'active' to true. I don't want to do this before the user interacts with the change password email, but am not sure how to do it otherwise. Some help would be appreciated!

```
  login(email: string, password: string): void {
      this.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        var userId = value.user.uid;
        this.db.database.ref(('users/' + userId)).get().then(value => {
          var userInfo = value.toJSON();
          if ( userInfo['active'] == false ) {
            this.router.navigate(['changepw']);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
        alert(err.message);
      });
    }
```

```
  sendResetEmail() {
    this.clearErrorMessage()

    this.authService.resetPassword(this.email)
      .then(() => this.resetPassword = true)
      .catch(_error => {
        this.error = _error
      })
  }
```

```
<div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="welcome"><p>Resetting your password</p>
      <p>Fill out the fields below. If an email is found in our system we will send reset instructions to it.</p></div>
      <form class="form">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-control">
          <mat-label><i>E-Mail</i></mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" id="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" required>
          <mat-hint>Enter your account's e-mail address</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-control">
          <mat-label><i>Password</i></mat-label>
          <input matInput type="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" required>
          <mat-hint>Enter your current password</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="form-footer"><br>
          <p><a *ngIf="!resetPassword && isValidMailFormat(email)" class="text-danger" (click)="sendResetEmail()">Click to send reset instructions to {{email}}</a></p>
          <p *ngIf="resetPassword" class="text-success">Check your email for instructions on how to reset your password!</p>
          
        </div><br><br>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```